# Data Factory Copy Activity: Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'xxx.csv' with row number 6696: found more columns than expected

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to perform a simply copy activity in Azure Data Factory from CSV to SQL Table, but I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'organizations.csv' with row number 6696: found more columns than expected column count 41.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

The copy activity is as follows

Source
[image]

[image]

My Sink is as follows:

[image]

[image]

As preview of the data in source is as follows:

[image]

This seems like a very straight forward copy activity. Any thoughts on what might be causing the error?

My row 6696 looks like the following:

3b1a2e5f-d08b-166b-4b91-eb53009b2377    Compassites Software Solutions  organization    compassites-software    https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/compassites-software    318375  17/07/2008 10:46    05/12/2022 12:17        company compassitesinc.com  http://www.compassitesinc.com   IND     Karnataka   Bangalore   "Pradeep Court", #163/B, 6th Main 3rd Cross, JP Nagar 3rd phase 560078  operating   Custom software solution experts    Big Data,Cloud Computing,Information Technology,Mobile,Software Data and Analytics,Information Technology,Internet Services,Mobile,Software                 01/11/2005          51-100  info@compassitesinc.com 080-42032572    http://www.facebook.com/compassites http://www.linkedin.com/company/compassites-software-solutions  http://twitter.com/compassites  https://res.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/v1397190270/c3e5acbde40f36eaf4f8c6f6eda3f803.png              company

No commas

Comment: Any help with this will be much appreicated.

Comment: Have you checked the line it has an issue with, it is seeing more columns delimited that it is expecting. Has it not been double quoted? Or some other item is causing an issue??

Comment: In your source file that you trying to read, remove all the rows before row number 6696 then try to preview the file in ADF and see where the extra column is generated. This is most likely due to a comma that adding an extra column in your CSV.

Comment: Ahhhh .... beshr, I see. I will try that later this morning. I will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, there is a record at row number 6696 where there is a value containing `,` as a character in it.

- Look at the following demonstration where I have taken a similar case. I have 3 columns in my source. The data looks as shown below:

[image]

- When I run use similar dataset settings and read these values, the same error would be thrown.

[image]

- So, the value `T1,OG` is being considered as if they belong to 2 different columns since they have dataset delimiter within the value.
- Such values would throw an error as it is ambiguous to read. One way to avoid this is to enclose such values with quote character (double quote in this case).

[image]

- Now when I run the copy activity, it would give the desired output.

[image]

- The table data would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Saideep, I'm looking into this now.. going to check out row 6696

Comment: Hi @Saideep, I have updated the question showing what row 6696 looks like. You will see there isn't any commas that would force another columns

Comment: The error message says that there are 41 columns in total. But the given 6696 row is not delimited to that many columns. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Saideep, that is a good point. When I manually count the columns, I'm onlty counting 40 columns. Therefore, I don't understand why its counting 41